# What is the best way of parsing a string to insert variables?

Tags: php

I have a string like this:
`"Hello, I am $name, it's nice to meet $noun".`

It comes directly from the database, and the `$` is escaped. I also have an array like this:
`[ 'name' => "Jawsh", 'noun' => "you" ]`

How would I replace variables in `$string` with the value of the corresponding array data?

Comment: Using [str_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) perhaps? `$myString = str_replace(array_keys($myArray), $myArray, $myString);` though you don't say how the `$` is escaped

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Have you looked into while loops?

Comment: @Rizier123 I could try many things to accomplish this, but I'm not asking for a way to do it, I'm asking for what is objectively the best way. I essentially want to do the same run-time variable concatenation as the string entails but with a string from the database. Mark Baker's method is good, but I would appear to need to make the array keys "$name" and "$noun" respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do so:

```
$string = "Hello, I am \$name, it's nice to meet \$noun.";
$array = array('name' => "Jawsh",'noun' => "you");

echo preg_replace_callback('/\$([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*)/', function($match) use ($array) {
    if (isset($array[$match[1]])) {
        return $array[$match[1]];
    }

    return $match[0];
}, $string);
```

> Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid
>   variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any
>   number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression,
>   it would be expressed thus: '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Comment: I like this a lot. I was playing around with preg replace loop but this may take the cake.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$string = "Hello, I am $name, it's nice to meet $noun.";
$array = [
    'name' => "Jawsh",
    'noun' => "you"
]

$string = str_replace('$name', $array['name'], $string);
$string = str_replace('$noun', $array['noun'], $string);
```

Comment: [And what happens if string containg similar variable, like `$string = "Hello, I am \$nameeeee, it's nice to meet \$noun.";`?](https://eval.in/369145)

Answer (score 0):

Simple example with `extract()` and `eval()`:

```php
extract($variables);
eval('$string = "' . $string . '";');
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/369142)</kbd>

Comment: And what happens if you [can't trust the code in the database](https://eval.in/369151)?

Comment: It is a viable answer. BUT! Quote: `If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question.`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) in conjunction with the `/e` flag to achive this:

```
$string = "Hello, I am \$name, it's nice to meet \$noun";
$replacements = array('name' => 'Jawsh', 'noun' => 'you');
$result  = preg_replace('/\$([a-z]+)/e', '$replacements["$1"]', $string);
print $result;
```

The above will print out `Hello, I am Jawsh, it's nice to meet you`.

Notice that the `e` pattern modifier was deprecated in PHP 5.5 and removed as of PHP 7.0

Comment: _The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead_ (deprecated in php 5.5.x)